# Jewish theodicy on natural evil

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, evil-resha, suffering, theodicy

Serious question. I understand the free will explanation for why God allows people to do evil things. But why does God allow what is classically called "natural evil"? For example, why does God allow small children to develop cancer? Thanks.

Comment: Are you essentially asking, 'why do bad things happen to good people'?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16494/15256 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29852/15256 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83733/15256

Comment: Kind of but not really. My question isn't about why bad things happen to adults. My question is more about children. toddlers or infants who have never done anything wrong and therefore do not deserve divine retribution. I give the example of cancer in my question. Why would God, who is said to be perfect in Justice, allow an infant to get cancer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does G-d punish the innocent?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109456/does-g-d-punish-the-innocent)? Or maybe this [Why did people under 100 die in the mabul?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109227/why-did-people-under-100-die-in-the-mabul)?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/130262/7303